# OpenShift: Accessing mounted file-system as non-root

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, openshift, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes

I am trying to run [Chart Museum](https://chartmuseum.com/) as a non-root user in OpenShift. Here is a snapshot of my YAML.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chart-museum
  namespace: demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chart-museum
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: chart-museum
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: pvc-charts
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-charts      
      containers:
        - name: chart-museum
          securityContext:
            fsGroup: 1000
          image: chartmuseum/chartmuseum:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: chart-museum
          volumeMounts:
            - name: pvc-charts
              mountPath: "/charts"
```

As you can see, I have set `spec.containers.securityContext.fsGroup` to `1000` which is same as the user ID in the Chart Museum `Dockerfile` as shown below.

```
FROM alpine:3.10.3
RUN apk add --no-cache cifs-utils ca-certificates \
    && adduser -D -u 1000 chartmuseum
COPY bin/linux/amd64/chartmuseum /chartmuseum
USER 1000
ENTRYPOINT ["/chartmuseum"]
```

And, yet, when I try to [upload a chart](https://github.com/helm/chartmuseum#uploading-a-chart-package), I get a permission denied message for `/charts`. How do I get around this issue?

Comment: fsGroup is a member of the spec.template.spec.securityContext, not of the spec.template.spec.containers.securityContext. It would work then and set group RW permissions on the mounted volume(s) to the supplied gid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue.

1. Download the binary `curl -LO https://s3.amazonaws.com/chartmuseum/release/latest/bin/linux/amd64/chartmuseum`.
2. Change permissions `chmod +xr chartmuseum`
3. Create a new `Dockerfile` as shown below. Basically, use the user name instead of ID for `chown` commands so that the binary and the storage location are owned by `chartmuseum` user and not `root`.

```
FROM alpine:3.10.3
RUN apk add --no-cache cifs-utils ca-certificates \
    && adduser -D -u 1000 chartmuseum
COPY chartmuseum /chartmuseum
RUN chown chartmuseum:chartmuseum /chartmuseum
RUN chown chartmuseum:chartmuseum /charts
USER chartmuseum
ENTRYPOINT ["/chartmuseum"]
```

4. Build and push the resulting Docker image to e.g. `somerepo/chartmuseum:0.0.0`.
5. Use the k8s manifest as shown below. Edit the namespace as required. **Note**, creation of `PersistentVolumeClaim` is not covered here.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: chart-museum
  namespace: demo
data:
  DEBUG: 'true'
  STORAGE: local
  STORAGE_LOCAL_ROOTDIR: "/charts"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chart-museum
  namespace: demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chart-museum
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: chart-museum
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: pvc-charts
          persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: pvc-charts
      containers:
        - name: chart-museum
          image: somerepo/chartmuseum:0.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: chart-museum
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/charts"
              name: pvc-charts
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: us.icr.io.secret
---              
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: chart-museum
  name: chart-museum
  namespace: demo
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: 8080-tcp
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: chart-museum
---
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  labels:
    app: chart-museum
  name: chart-museum
  namespace: demo
spec:
  port:
    targetPort: 8080-tcp
  tls:
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
    termination: edge
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: chart-museum
```

The manifest creates a `ConfigMap` object and uses a `PersistentVolumeClaim` to 'replicate' the command to run Chart Museum locally (as described at https://chartmuseum.com/)

```sh
 docker run --rm -it \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v $(pwd)/charts:/charts \
  -e DEBUG=true \
  -e STORAGE=local \
  -e STORAGE_LOCAL_ROOTDIR=/charts \
  chartmuseum/chartmuseum:latest
```

The `Service` and `Route` in the manifest expose the repo to the external world.

6. After the objects are created, enter the `HOST/PORT` value in `oc get route/chart-museum -n demo` with `https` in address bar and hit enter. You should see a welcome page for Chart Museum. This means the installation is successful.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to Kubernetes and how the given Persistent Volume is defined. You can check all the discussion and possible workarounds in the [related GH Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630).

Comment: Let me try the option of adding a `chown` (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630#issuecomment-523683984) As mentioned in my question, the `fsGroup` option (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630#issuecomment-554348473) hasn't worked for me actually.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `chmod/chown` lines in your dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.10.3
RUN apk add --no-cache cifs-utils ca-certificates \
    && adduser -D -u 1000 chartmuseum
COPY bin/linux/amd64/chartmuseum /chartmuseum
RUN chmod +xr /chartmuseum
RUN chown 1000:1000 /chartmuseum
USER 1000
ENTRYPOINT ["/chartmuseum"]
```

Modify your *spec.template.spec.containers.securityContext* to ensure the user and group will be enforced.

```
      containers:
        - name: chart-museum
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1000
            runAsGroup: 1000
            fsGroup: 1000
```

Comment: The YAML for deployment was considered valid only when `fsGroup` was removed. Then, the deployment failed with this reason `unable to validate against any security context constraint: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 1000: must be in the ranges: [1000350000, 1000359999]]`

Comment: The issue is with `/charts`. How does your `Dockerfile` resolve that issue? And with `spec.template.spec.containers`, `fsGroup` was called out as invalid. The numerical values of `runAsUser` and `runAsGroup` was found to be too low and the container never started.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenShift, check the following, one by one, and you shall be able to run an OCI container mounting a persistent volume and running with a given User ID within your project.

1. OpenShift won't allow to run payloads as uid=0, i.e. 'root' and instead generate a random UID to launch your CMD or ENTRYPOINT commands. Hence, ensure that beyond build you enforce USER uid:gid with relevant uid/gid numbers for your JVM, web server, Node, database server when launched
2. OpenShift will ignore this USER directive unless your pods will be allowed to use a specific userID in place of the default random userID. Henceforth, ensure that the 'default' service account of your project (the one forking pods) is bound to the SCC (Security Context Constraint) "anyuid" (Cluster Role: system:openshift:scc:anyuid). For instance, as cluster:admin or system:admin you can use the 'oc CLI' tool and execute:

   `oc whoami  #to check that you are logged in as cluster or system admin
   oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -n myProjectName -z default`
3. The volumes that you request in a PVC will be mounted as... root:root at the mount point! At most your payload - now running as USER uid:gid will be able to read, but not write, hence cannot persist any data! ... unless you enforce a mount for a specified groupID via the { securityContext: { fsGroup: myGID } } object in your container Deployment manifests. For instance:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: mongo
      namespace: veniqa-demo
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - image: gitlab.example.com:5050/demo/veniqa/mongo:latest
              name: mongo
              ports:
                - containerPort: 27017
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /data/configdb
                  name: dbmongo
                  subpath: db/config
                - mountPath: /data/db
                  name: dbmongo
                  subpath: db/data
          securityContext:
            fsGroup: 999
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: veniqa-gitlab-registry-deploytoken
          volumes:
            - name: dbmongo
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: dbmongo
```